# Stop program execution until threads complete

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

I have a console application that inits 4 theads to perform a long task. I want my program to wait until the threads are complete, and then complete the program execution. Is there a way to stop the program from executing, letting the threads complete their job?

Answer (score 15):

[Threading.Thread.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join.aspx) is what you are looking for.

Edit: Examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Load your application after those threads are joined e.g:

```
Thread1.join();
Thread2.join();
Thread3.join();
Thread4.join();


startApplication();
```

If you could provide me in more detail i can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon how you're starting the 4 threads then WaitHandle.WaitAll might be a good place to start...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Thread.Join is what you want.